# Focus Skips When User Types Fast

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on date input on a web page. I have the date as three input fields. The plan is when two characters have been typed into the first field the focus goes automatically to the next field and all the text in that field is to be selected. When 2 digits have been typed into this field the next field is then automatically focused. I have this working using a javascript function on onkeyup. The HTML is (dates for me are day-month-year format):

```
    <input id="dobDay" style="width:30px" maxlength="2"
        onkeyup="CheckIfFieldIsFull(event, this, 2, dobMonth)"
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >
    /
    <input id="dobMonth" style="width:30px;" maxlength="2"
        onkeyup="CheckIfFieldIsFull(event, this, 2, dobYear)"
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >
    /
    <input id="dobYear" style="width:50px" maxlength="4" 
        onkeyup="CheckIfFieldIsFull(event, this, 4, IdOfNextField)"
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >
```

and the javascript:

```
function CheckIfFieldIsFull(e, CurrentField, MaxChars, IDOfNextField) {
  if (e.keyCode != 9 && 
      CurrentField.value.length >= MaxChars)
  {
    document.getElementById(IDOfNextField.id).focus();
  }
}
```

This all works as required *at normal typing speed*. If the fields are already populated with some data and the user types 2 different characters fast into the first field then instead of the cursor being in the second field it will have jumped to the 3rd field :-(

This doesn't happen when the field that will be given focus is empty or only has 1 character in it, it only happens when the field has maxlength characters already in it.

I am pretty sure this is because the first key has not done a keyup event by the time the user has hit the second key. I say this because if you type two of the same character into the first field as quickly as you can the problem will not occur (when it is the same physical key you can't do key press before the previous keyup has occurred).

Any ideas what is causing this problem or how to avoid it ?

Tell the users to type slower ?!

I have tried onkeypress() instead of onkeyup() but it has other problems (mainly the CurrentField.value will not be updated to reflect the key just pressed so length doesn't give anything relevant).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use keydown event and setTimeout to define value and move focus:

HTML:

`<input id="dobDay" style="width:30px" maxlength="2"
        onkeydown="CheckIfFieldIsFull(event, this, 2, dobMonth)"
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >
    /
    <input id="dobMonth" style="width:30px;" maxlength="2"
        onkeydown="CheckIfFieldIsFull(event, this, 2, dobYear)"
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >
    /
    <input id="dobYear" style="width:50px" maxlength="4" 
        onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;"
        >`

JS:

`window.CheckIfFieldIsFull = function (e, CurrentField, MaxChars, IDOfNextField) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (e.keyCode != 9 && CurrentField.value.length >= MaxChars) {
            var next = document.getElementById(IDOfNextField.id);
            next.focus();
        }
    }, 0);
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/f5sesoay/2/

Comment: This seems to work perfectly in jsfiddle. I will try it on my page as soon as I can. Thank you Rodion

Comment: I tried it on my page and it works, my problem is fixed, users are happy !. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/t1zfp8ma/

New link http://jsfiddle.net/t1zfp8ma/6/

```
<input class="date" id="dobDay" style="width:30px" maxlength="2">/
<input class="date" id="dobMonth" style="width:30px;" maxlength="2">/
<input class="date" id="dobYear" style="width:50px" maxlength="4">

$('.date').keyup(function (e) {
if($(this).val().length == 2 && $(this).hasClass('dirty')){
    $(this).removeClass('dirty');
    $(this).next().removeClass('dirty').select();
}
}).keydown(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('dirty');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the example on jsfiddle shows the problem behaviour. In your jsfiddle example if you type some values into the fields ie 10 11 and 2013, click in the 1st field and then quickly type two digits (say 1 and 2 because there are next to each other on the keyboard so are easy to type quickly) you will see that the cursor has skipped to the 3rd field instead of sitting in the 2nd field. If you click into the 1st field and then type 1, pause for a second and then type 2 the cursor will go to the 2nd field (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for helping. In your jsfiddle example you use keypress. keypress has problems - for example type 2 digits into a field - the cursor doesn't move to the next field. It isn't until you press a 3rd character that it moves. Also when the fields are full of characters and you click into a field even though the contents are selected, and it looks like you can type a new value in, as soon as you type 1 character the cursor is taken to the next field. The onkeypress event fires before the fields value has changed so the length == 2 test returns a kind of false positive.

Answer (score 0):

It is works for we if I reset value on the next field before focus on it

`var next = document.getElementById(IDOfNextField);
next.value = '';
next.focus();`

http://jsfiddle.net/f5sesoay/

Comment: Yes clearing the field does stop the skipping (as I said in the post it only happens when the field is populated with a value) but I need the value to be shown to the user so that they can just tab over the field when it's value will not be changed.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that. I'll try to think another way